# Magento Template Design Question

Tags: magento

In the category page of Magento, the default setting is three columns and three products a line.

When I remove the left column, it appeares blank in the left sidebar and the content of the products will not be auto-width. So I need to change the CSS file so that make the page looks fine.

I am new to Magento, the question is, is this the best practise or is there another way to make this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit the default layout but rather create another page template (ie. 2columns.phtml) and then add it into the page.xml as well as adding your css for the new layout.

To change the default layout, open:

/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/page.xml

on or around line 35, edit the following block:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
```

change to

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-right.phtml">
```

and then add your css accordingly.

Comment: @Ruiwant, the important part here is that "2columns-right.phtml" (and "2columns-left.phtml") already exists and is available and you can use it without hacking the CSS. Google can help you find out how.